# Two C# project files for VS2010 and VS2012 in the same directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm writing a C# project which I want to compile both under VS2010 and VS2012. I want to have two different `.csproj` files for that, even though VS2010-project can be directly included in VS2012-solution. I want two different project files because of different target .NET-versions.

Additionally, I want both projects to be named the same within different solutions for VS2010 and VS2012. The both should share the same `.cs`-files and, possibly, some resources.

Easy task? Strange thing, but I don't know, how to do that properly.

- First approach, doesn't work: name project files as `MyProject10.csproj` and `MyProject12.csproj`, leave both in the `MyProject` folder. But in this case they are displayed in solution as `MyProject10` and `MyProject12`, not simply `MyProject`. If I rename one to `MyProject` in solution explorer, it automatically renames the corresponding project file.
- Second approach, works, but has drawbacks. Move project files into different subdirectories, named `VS10` and `VS12`, manually change include paths in `.csproj`-files, adding `..\` as a prefix. In this case I see strange shortcut-like arrows under the icons in solution explorer.

The only bad thing for the second approach is that when I add new files in the project using solution explorer, this file is placed in the `VS10` subdirectory, not in the root project directory. But it seems like project directories for `.csproj`-files are the directories containing the file by design, and I use the dark side of the force which I really don't want to do.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Why not have one project with two different build configuratoins?

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I want to compile to .NET 4 under VS2010 and to .NET 4.5 under VS2012. I suppose I should have two different projects for that.

Comment: It's possible to target different versions of .NET in one project with different configurations - you need to edit the project files manually, but it's possible.

Comment: But both configurations will be visible under VS2010 and VS2012. I don't think it's eligible.

Comment: I believe that under the Project Properties, you can change the "Target framework" option to whichever .NET version you want.

Comment: @Bob Yes, but for both VS, while I need one version in VS10 and other in VS11. And additional configurations have fore-mentioned disadvantage.

Comment: I use a build script (MSBuild) to compile against more than one framework version, then in the IDE only ever work against the lower version.

Answer (score 0):

Worth giving a try is changing the name of the output assembly in both projects to one and the same. The project files are still going to be different, but the output assembly will be with same name. Also be carefull where is the output directory. I think this way you can sovle your problem.